# Unsupported operand types adding value to global variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-7

I get

> USER ERROR: "Unsupported operand types"

in code when using the global variable `$USER` what select all data from user table and add to it data what is selected from statistic table.

```
 $sql   = 'SELECT total_points
            FROM %%STATPOINTS%%
            WHERE id_owner = :userId AND stat_type = :statType';

$USER   += Database::get()->selectSingle($sql, array(
                ':userId'   => $USER['id'],
                ':statType' => 1
            ));
```

Error shows that fault is in this line `':statType' => 1` but if I change it then it shows that fault is in `':userId'  => $USER['id'],` .

PHP version 7.0!

Comment: is this a typo? `$USER   +=`?

Comment: I think no, this is mean to be that way. But I think that is what causing a problem.

Comment: i don't know whats the real return value on that, but what i would do is initialize it properly. `$USER = 0;` up top

Comment: and im guessing this line `Database::get()` is supposed to yield a number and ideally to incrementally add into `$USER`, by the look of things i think you need to point to the index on the return value properly. or fetch the `total_points` properly, then use `+=`

Comment: `$USER` is a global variable what holds data for all users. I cannot set it to 0. `$USERS` holds all selected data from `users table`.

Comment: then you've answered your question, why are you assigning `total_points` to `$USER` then, if `$USER` is populated initially with `total_points` maybe you oughta assign it as `$USER['total_poiints'] += whatever query that returns a number`

Comment: It's there because `STATPOINTS`and `USERS` are two different tables.  The idea what I understand from a guy what done that was to add stat points table info to users